# Adding objects to arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

// I have an array

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray allot] init];
```

// I want to add a string object. I can add it either using this:

```
NSString *aString = @"A random string";
[anArray addObject:aString];
```

// But I can also do this:

```
[anArray addObject:@"A random string"];
```

For the second option, this creates a new string object. I can't explicitly access this object, but I can access it with the array with objectAtIndex:. **But why would one ever use the first option then?**

Comment: The name of the variable might indicate what the string represents better. If the string is long you might be able to format the code better the first way. In reality they do identical things - the compiler will optimize out any differences, so do whichever is more readable.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that was a complete answer I don't know why you put it as a comment!

Comment: zaph had already answered it and I was just adding a little bit of info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases `@"A random string"` is created at compile-time. Personally I used the single statement. It really does not make any difference, the compiler will most likely optimize away the temporary `aString`.

As for "But why would one ever use the first option then?" let me ask why anyone would wear black instead of brown shoes? Personal preference.